# use statement not working in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I am creating my first AppleScript library in a script file, and would like to use the handlers in that file using the `use` statement ([I followed these instructions](http://macosxautomation.com/mavericks/usestatement/index.html)). So I tried:

```
use script "My Library"

create_new_track(10, 2, 2)
```

Inside my "My Library.scpt" file, there is a handler called "create_new_track".
But when I try to call it after the use statement, I get this error:

```
error "«script» doesn’t understand the “create_new_track” message." number -1708 from «script»
```

With the following snippet, I get get the handler to run though:

```
tell script "My Library"
    create_new_track(10, 2, 2)
end tell
```

I would rather be able to avoid numerous tell blocks in my script, though. Anyone got an idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're assuming AppleScript's library system was designed by a competent engineer. This is not so: like almost everything the current AppleScript team spews out, it's the software version of a clown car: totally unpredictable, dangerously unsafe, and the moment you think you've finally figured out correctly how it works, all the doors fly off and dozens of lunatic clowns leap out and pelt you with unspeakable substances.

Anyway, to try and explain the insanity best I can...

The `use` statement injects dictionary-defined keywords into your global namespace. This in itself is an insane thing to do, considering that AppleScript is already notorious for creating terminology clashes between language, application, and scripting addition dictionaries.

However, the `use` statement does *not* inject user-defined identifiers (e.g. your `create_new_track` identifier). Which is somewhat ironic, given that user-defined identifiers are far, far safer to mix than arbitrary keywords, and it would make ObjC frameworks vastly less annoying to use (I mean, what on Earth possessed them to think `current application's NSWhatever...` is good syntax?!?!!).

While AppleScript does have problems binding static variable names correctly, handler names are always dynamically bound so user-defined command names normally work without problem (the message just passes up the object delegate chain until it's handled or a "handler not found" error occurs). However, the `use` mechanism doesn't use standard AppleScript delegation (not that it was intended for this kind of use anyway), but instead appears to rely on a global lookup table of known keywords to intercept messages with keyword-based names and redirect those messages to whatever object originally defined that keyword. But since your `create_new_track` message doesn't have a keyword based name, this "redirect" hack completely ignores it; an AppleScript Apartheid, if you will.

Therefore, if you want to refer to properties and handlers that have user-defined names within a script library, you *must* use a reference, e.g. `create_new_track() of script "MyLibrary"`. This is actually a Good Thing, and brings the whole mess as near to "simple, predictable, and safe" as it ever gets, because it leaves all your scripts' namespaces intact and doesn't inject any more potentially conflicting keywords into AppleScript's global namespace.

If you're using a library repeatedly, then writing `...of script "MyLibrary"` does get tedious. While you could use a `tell script "MyLibrary"...end tell` block to wrap multiple commands, excessive use of `tell` blocks is another easy way to create total confusion since they specify the default target for *all* commands within the block, not just the ones you actually want sent to that object. The best solution is to use a `property` statement at the top of your script to bind the `script...` specifier to a nice, neat identifier, which you can then use throughout the rest of the script whenever you need to send a command to that library:

```
property mylib : script "My Library"

...

mylib's do_this()

mylib's do_that()

etc.
```

Use this approach, and you'll avoid a ton of pain. Try to be "clever", and it'll almost invariably bite you in the ass. Mastering the AppleScript language has always been as much about learning its many defects and how to work around them as in actually learning to code. It's just unfortunate that the current AS team is so devoted to indulging its own pathological cleverness that this becomes *harder*, not easier, year after year. (I expect AS to surpass C++ eventually, assuming the rest Apple doesn't just put a bullet in it first - something as a 15-year AS veteran I increasingly wish they'd do before it strangles user scripting and automation completely.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. To tell you the truth, I have actually liked the use clause a lot, compared to the previous state, (I actually wrote a library server, that let one call handlers from a stay open applet. :). I'll certainly read through your post thoroughly, and will probably adapt your way of doing stuff as a new usage pattern. Your way also fits well with store script and load script I guess. (But I'll try it out.)

Comment: I think what foo meant is the dirty hack of having an sdef file in script libraries. Developers who are not aware of the vulnerabilities, like global namespace pollution but also apple event code pollution (something that is hardly mentioned by Apple), makes sharing libraries impossible. To avoid all of that you stick with user defined names instead of enumerated/keyed names. In short, AppleScript is "safer" when you address your objects in a verbose way instead of putting everything in the global namespace.

Comment: Not impossible, but it greatly increases the likelihood of scripts going wrong in bizarre and unpredictable ways. The `global` and `use` statements are both fundamentally evil because they totally destroy script object encapsulation and so should never be used with or in libraries. The whole point of library-based construction is to manage complexity and avoid chaos, not create it, otherwise it's actually simpler and safer sticking to copy-and-paste. The _only_ time the `use` statement is safe to use (and also unavoidable) is when importing ObjC frameworks and, in turn, scripting additions.

Answer (score 1):

Pointing out some useful information… If you choose the route of using a property to define a script library to be able to call handlers and script objects to be used in other scripts, it is important to keep in mind that, if any changes are made to your script library file… and is recompiled and saved, those changes will not carry over to the scripts you have created, which call script objects and handlers from your library file.  In short, you will need to open and recompile and save every single script created which calls on script objects and handlers from your library file.  This can become a nightmare if you have dozens or even hundreds of scripts.

Using this following example from one of the other answers…   the script library gets stored at compile time and will retain its value until the script is recompiled. Any updates or changes to the original library file will not be reflected in the scripts calling on them until those scripts are recompiled and saved as well

```
property mylib : script "My Library"

...

mylib's do_this()

mylib's do_that()

etc.
```

In my opinion a more favorable option would be to load the script library at run time.  This way, any script which depends on that library file, will automatically be updated when it is run… after the script library file has been altered and saved.

This is the code that I use to load libraries at runtime

```
property myLib : missing value
property theLibrary : missing value

on loadLibraries()
    set theLibrary to (path to home folder as text) & "Library:Script Libraries:My Library.scpt"
    set myLib to load script alias theLibrary
end loadLibraries

loadLibraries()

myLib's do_this()
myLib's do_that()
```

Comment: This is a lifesaver. Thank you. I'd had the comical workflow of "copy all my code over into a new Script Editor window each time I make a change to my library", and this lets my code reliably use the most up-to-date version of my library.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd try:

```
 use mylib : script "My Library"
 mylib's create_new_track(10, 2, 2)
```

If I have got it right, you can only use use statements as you have done above, in order to use the terminology from an app. -But I may have gotten that wrong.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using `property <identifier>:<specifier>`, _not_ `use <identifier>:<specifier>`. The latter is fundamentally brain-damaged: while binds the identifier to the specifier as you'd expect, it _simultaneously_ imports the specified object's entire contents into your script, which you totally don't. (If you'd wanted your global namespace polluted, you wouldn't have bound it to an identifier in the first place.)

Comment: I actually haven't tried that, I guess you mean for instance: `property matrix : script "Matrix"`?

Comment: @McUsr The solution you proposed worked for me, thanks! So do I understand this right: For my original code to work, I need to have a "Library with Terminology"?

Comment: @foo: I tried with `property <identifier>:<specifier>` and that works! So this only imports the handlers that are called, correct?

Comment: `property <identifier>:<specifier>` defines a convenient shortcut for referring to the library. It doesn't add anything to your script's own namespace. (`property mylib : script "MyLibrary"` is basically equivalent to using `import mylib` in Python and `use script "MyLibrary"` is equivalent to `from mylib import *`, while `use mylib : script "MyLibrary"` is like using _both_.)

Comment: Oh, and avoid "Libraries with Terminology" like the plague, [for that way insanity lies](http://lovecraft.wikia.com/wiki/Cthulhu).